# error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno_t'

Tags: c, clang, c11, errno, tr24731

Here is my dead simple dummy code:

```
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    errno_t e;
    return 0;
}
```

Which surprisingly raises this error:

```
main.c:5:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno_t'
    errno_t x;
    ^
```

I started to *follow the traces*: when the compiler sees the `<...>` inclusions it will first look at `/usr/include` where of course I found `errno.h` file. Actually it has a single line in it, besides the license comment, which is:

```
#include <sys/errno.h>
```

Now, at `/usr/include/sys` in `errno.h` I found the following lines:

```
#include <sys/cdefs.h>

#if defined(__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__) && __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ >= 1
#include <sys/_types/_errno_t.h>
#endif
```

And at `/usr/include/_types` in `_errno_t.h` I found this:

```
typedef int errno_t;
```

So it looks like, it is there, and it is an alias of the integer type, and part of the `errno.h` -- just as it should be.

Then why isn't it included? Why the compiler raises the undeclared identifier error?

Thanks in advance!

---

***RELEVANT INFO:***

```
Compiler:
    Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`

Compiler flags:
    -std=c11 -I/usr/include/sys -I/usr/local/include
```

---

The macro variable `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` will be defined at `/usr/include/sys` in `cdefs.h` in the following lines:

```
/* If the developer has neither requested a strict language mode nor a version
 * of POSIX, turn on functionality provided by __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ as part
 * of __DARWIN_C_FULL.
 */
#if !defined(__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__) && __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#endif
```

---

***UPDATE:***

As @PaulR said in the comment section: if I remove the `-std=c11` flag, it compiles. Which is just as surprising as the error raised if the flag was included. So I extend this question with a sub-question:

*Is not `errno_t` part of the C11 standard, or why isn't it included, when the standard is specified for the compiler?*

Comment: Are you including `cdefs.h` (directly or through other includes)? `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` is defined on a condition. Is that condition met?

Comment: @BlueMoon updated the post -- the `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` has the inclusion before it checks if the var is defined or not

Comment: It's because you're compiling with `-std=c11` - take that out, or use the less strict `-std=gnu11`, and it will compile just fine.

Comment: @PaulR you are right.. can you explain why is this happening? afaik `errno_t` is part of the C11 standard to, isn't it?

Comment: That's a different question, and one I don't know the answer to. ;-)

Comment: @PeterVaro: No, it's part of Annex K, which is not normative except for implementations which claim to support it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`errno_t` is not a standard type; it's part of the optional (and widely disliked and unsupported) Annex K, included with ISO C11 only because of one particular vendor with a history of ignoring and sabotaging the standard.

Since Annex K defines `errno_t` as `int`, the type of the `errno` object is `int`, and all error codes are `int`, simply use `int` in your programs. It's much more portable than relying on an optional feature which is unlikely to be supported.

Comment: Give them time - it's taken 15 years for them to get to grips with C99!

Comment: The bigger issue is that they've made a point of trying to impose their useless additions to the language into a standard that they have no interest or intention in following. That's not the way standards are supposed to work. If you don't want to follow the standard you shouldn't participate in trying to shape it.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Why not? In that position I’d want the standard to follow *me*.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: What I mean by "you shouldn't participate" is not that I expect someone in that position to voluntarily exclude themselves. It's a statement that I think the standards processes should be designed to be robust against such bad actors and exclude them from participating when they have a history of trying to shape it then refusing to follow it.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Of course. I was being sarcastic but forgot that I’m on the internet where sarcasm is… difficult.