# Android NDK compiling C++ code gets a Type 'errno_t' could not be resolved

Tags: android, c++, macos, android-ndk

I'm compiling C++ code written primarily for Mac OS, using the Android NDK and I get the following error:

```
- Type 'errno_t' could not be resolved
```

In Xcode this type is defined on OSX 10.0/usr/include/sys/_types/_errno_t.h as this:

```
#ifndef _ERRNO_T
#define _ERRNO_T
typedef int                    errno_t;  
#endif  /* _ERRNO_T */
```

Any suggestions on how to convert this to the NDK, or add compiler flags to make this compile, or where to even get the source code to define this type in my source code itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `errno_t` a POSIX / ISO type?  I don't see it defined under Linux.  You may just need to define it yourself in a header if `_ERRNO_T` isn't defined (as in your question), or just throw `-Derrno_t=int` in your makefile.

Comment: it seems to be an int, at least in Obj-C, so im going with that for not until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207339/632035) for information on `errno_t`.

`errno_t` is not a part of the C standard, and bionic doesn't support it.

The fix is simply to change all the `errno_t`s to be `int`s.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Thanks